# Are newer CUDA versions in a major series (11.x, 12.x) backwards compatible with another?

Tags: cuda, nvidia

We have been tending to "side-by-side" install all the CUDA versions of a given major series - for instance, for CUDA 11, we install 11.0, 11.1, ..., 11.8. Do we really need to do that, or is just the latest CUDA version in a major release all we need (anotherwords, are they backwards compatible?) We sometimes need to run old code compiled with a older version of CUDA, so at a minimum, we'd need 10.x, 11.x and now 12.x. Can I just install the latest/last version of 10.x, 11.x and 12.x and be covered?

Comment: I think they are following semantic versioning, i.e. minor versions should only add features, not break existing interfaces.

Comment: Am expecting that to be the case, but want to know for sure...

Comment: How much compatibility do you need? The programs should run with the newest CUDA version of a major release. But if you want to predict everything, you should even install the same driver version with the same hardware.

Comment: If a question about CUDA (programming libraries) doesn't belong on a programming q site, then I don't know where it does...

Answer (score 2):

See https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/cuda-compatibility/#minor-version-compatibility - seems the answer is "yes" to my question above, and really, only the latest 12.x version is needed if code compiled with CUDA 11.0+